# How to locate to a method in IDEA quickly in the outline by paste method name?

Tags: intellij-idea

In eclipse, we can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> to popup a outline view, and paste some text (copied from somewhere previously) and locate the corresponding method.

But in IDEA, althought there is a similar view (by press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>), but it doesn't support pasting, that I have to type the method name manually.

I wonder is it possible to locate the method declaration by pasting in IDEA?

Comment: I've just posted an issue in JetBrain's bug tracker. If you agree they should fix this, please go there and vote up: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145214

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the dialog. Start typing `a` (for example) to enter the search, then delete it, and paste.

It's kind of awkward, but it works, and once you get used to it, it really isn't an issue.

Comment: If you're on the method name (where it is called) simply use ctrl-b to go to the method definition, or ctrl-shift-b to go to the implementation. Alt-f7 will highlight uses of a given symbol.

Comment: This answer effectively does the trick, thanks for that, but it is unforgivable that people call this IDE "way more intelligent than Eclipse" when, features like this one are extremely basic (another one is viewing the implementation hierarchy of a method in a popup window)